# How to loop through and display a list of items gathered from firebase (realtime database)

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, firebase

I have an object I've received from Firebase, and now I need to somehow loop through it and display it.  Part of the issue is Firebase gives each entry in the schema a unique identifier, which means I have to do some javascript 'magic' to get my data.

Here's what I have so far, but I'm having issues with the whole key thing (the bellow currently gives a error of: `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`). I haven't found any definitive help online yet, so any help is appreciated.

Data in firebase looks something like this:

- fooData

  - giberish random id

    - title
    - date
    - markdown text

Edit: To be clear, the second part of this question is how should I extract the data I need?  (title, date, markdown).  This `map` function seems the most promising method, but I'm not sure how to get child elements.  Currently I do not get any info (null).  I'm assuming this is because the title, date, markdown children are one level deeper and do not exist on the current root element of the object.

```js
class Foo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            firebase: props.firebase,
            data: null
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const dataRef = firebase.database().ref('link/fooData');
        dataRef.on('value', snapshot => {
            this.setState({
                data: snapshot.val()
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
            {(this.state.data) ? (
                <div>
                    {Object.keys(this.state.data).map((key) => {
                        return (
                            <Row>
                                <Col lg={2}><p key={key}>{this.state.data[key].title}</p></Col>
                                <Col lg={2}><p key={key}>{this.state.data[key].date}</p></Col>
                                <Col lg={8}><ReactMarkdown key={key}>{this.state.data[key].markdownText}</ReactMarkdown></Col>
                            </Row>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            ) : null}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the the key like this

```
return (
        <Row key={key}>
           <Col lg={2}><p>{key.title}</p></Col>
              <Col lg={2}><p>{key.date}</p></Col>
                <Col lg={8}>
                  <ReactMarkdown >{key.markdownText} 
                  </ReactMarkdown>
                </Col>
        </Row>
 )
```

for more info you can refer [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Comment: Thanks!  This cleared up the keys issue.  The only thing that's left now is to figure out how to properly extract the data from the snapshot object.  I suppose this part wasn't clear in my question, I'll update it.

Comment: please provide the screenshot of the data or any info on the data you want to to display, is it an object or array?

Comment: I have provided some extra context for this bit in my question.  Essentially, I need the title, date, text as the above example shows, but I think it is one level deeper than where I am trying to grab it from (the unique ID), so it's currently just null.

Comment: We're getting closer, I suppose since the first level of the object is the random unique Id, I am un-able to dive down any more levels, since I don't know the field key.  I'm trying to look into this bit more.  I'll let you know if I find anything

Comment: @MatthewStrom if your issue has been solved, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

techguru's answer is valid, depending on your situation.  For me, however, I had to get past the unique keys in the firebase object.

To achieve this, I am using a forEach loop on the snapshot:

```js
dataRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach(item => {
        this.setState({data: this.state.data.concat(item.val().data)});
    });
});
```

From here I take the state and display the data in `render()`, similar to techguru's answer.

Hopefully this answer plus techguru's answer will give a good compilation of info :)